# VBA Outlook "No active explorer found"

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am experiencing an issue with Outlook automation,

To keep it simple I will first show you a shorter version of my code :

```
Sub test()
  Dim GetOutlookApp As Object

  Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub
```

First, I do want to keep the late binding solution.

This sub launch Outlook in the taskbar (small icon). When I double click on it, a message pops up: "No active explorer object found" (title of the window: "Error"). Then the Outlook Inbox window opens when I click on OK.

My script is for end users so I don't want this message appears even if the user just has to click on OK (the rest of the main sub has no one issue).

I have to solve this problem to be able to send an email with outlook and to make sure the email is not in the Outbox folder.

What I am looking for is a way to open outlook, without this message, using late binding.

Below is the full code to open outlook before sending the email (source: ron de bruin). It works perfectly except the outlook message. The message pops up on this line:

```
obj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Display
```

I tried AppActivate and others stuffs but I did not succeed and can't find any info on google about that!

Thanks for your help

```
Sub send_mail ()
   Dim OutApp  As Object
    Set OutApp = OutlookApp() 'OPEN OUTLOOK
    'Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'OPEN OUTLOOK simple solution


    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
     ...
    End With
End sub

Public Function OutlookApp( _
    Optional WindowState As Long = olMaximized, _
    Optional ReleaseIt As Boolean = True _
    ) As Object
'***This sub is a part to the global way to open outlook before sending an email (prevent the outbox bug, email stucked into the outbox)
'***Source: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm, late binding mode

Static obj As Object

On Error GoTo ErrHandler


    Select Case True
        Case obj Is Nothing, Len(obj.Name) = 0
            Set obj = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If obj.Explorers.Count = 0 Then
InitOutlook:
                'Open inbox to prevent errors with security prompts
                obj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Display
                obj.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = WindowState
            End If
        Case ReleaseIt
            Set obj = Nothing
    End Select
    Set OutlookApp = obj

ExitProc:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147352567
            'User cancelled setup, silently exit
            Set obj = Nothing
        Case 429, 462
        MsgBox "Err.Number OutlookApp: " & Err.Number
            Set obj = GetOutlookApp()
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                Err.Raise 429, "OutlookApp", "Outlook Application does not appear to be installed."
            Else
                Resume InitOutlook
            End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Unexpected error"
    End Select
    Resume ExitProc
    Resume
End Function

Private Function GetOutlookApp() As Object
'***This sub is a part to the global way to open outlook before sending an email (prevent the outbox bug, email stucked into the outbox)
'***Source: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm, late binding mode

'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

ExitProc:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            'Do not raise any errors
            Set GetOutlookApp = Nothing
    End Select
    Resume ExitProc
    Resume
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try turning `Application.DisplayAlerts= false`? Similarly you might try `OutlookApp.DisplayAlerts=false` although haven't tried that

Comment: Yes I tried, it did not fix the issue. :(
I forget to say that when using the VBA file, the message pops up on the "obj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Display" code line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220301%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Explorers class to create a new instance of the explorer window. Then you need to call the [Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff863904.aspx) method of the Explorer class (not Folder).

```
  Sub DisplayDrafts()
   Dim myExplorers As Outlook.Explorers
   Dim myOlExpl As Outlook.Explorer
   Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder

   Set myExplorers = Application.Explorers
   Set myFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
   Set myOlExpl = myExplorers.Add(myFolder, olFolderDisplayNoNavigation)
   myOlExpl.Display
  End Sub
```

> This sub launch Outlook in the taskbar (small icon). When I double click on it, a message pops up: "No active explorer object found" (title of the window: "Error"). Then the Outlook Inbox window opens when I click on OK.

Typically you shouldn't see any icons in the task bar. Make sure that you have all the latest updates and service packs installed for the OS and Outlook. Also check out the list of running processes before automating Outlook - make sure that no Outlook instances running at the moment.

See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, it works (with some modification for the late binding mode),
My code is in the next topic answer.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Eugene Astafiev code I have solved my issue! Thanks Eugene!

Here is the code:

Sub that send the email:

```
Sub Send_Mail()
'**This sub aims to send the mail that contains the job sheet

'Deactivate the screen updating : increase the speed and looks better
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Select the range of data
    ActiveSheet.Range(FirstCol_JS & 1 & ":" & LastCol_JS & Firstrow_JS + nb_item_scanned - 1).Select
    'Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook. This line prevents a bug (Method 'MailEnveloppe' of object '_Worksheet' failed. -2147467259, 80004005)
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    'Make sure outlook is opened or open it *****HERE IS WHY MY QUESTION*****
    Call OutlookApp <------------------------------------------------

    'Email error handling
    On Error GoTo ErrorManagement

    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
        'Subject is the title of the mail
        .Item.Subject = "Job Sheet"
        'Introduction is the content of the mail
        .Introduction = "Hi John," & vbCrLf & _
                        "..." & vbCrLf & _
                        "Regards, The computer"
       .Item.To = "alias@domain.com"
       .Item.Send
    End With

    'Select the home page (main sheet)
        'It is needed to activate the screenupdating so that the userform can be displayed on the sheet1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    'Normally, this message should never appear
    MsgBox "You can't create a job sheet without any item. Nothing was done.", , "Action not allowed"
End If

'Exit sub before the error handling codes
Exit Sub

ErrorManagement:
'Activate the screen updating : be able to show that the outlook interface disappears
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Hide the outlook interface
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

'Activate the Excel windows so that the msgbox does not appear in the Windows taskbar
'This line is mandatory because the outlook interface is in front of the Excel workbook when it appears, so we have to activate again the Excel worbook
Call ActivateExcel

End Sub
```

Principal sub that manage to open Outlook

```
Sub OutlookApp(Optional ReleaseIt As Boolean = True)
'***This sub is a part to the global way to open outlook before sending an email (prevent the outbox bug, email stucked into the outbox)
'***Source: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm, late binding mode, and Eugene Astafiev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198130/vba-outlook-no-active-explorer-found

'Declaration of an object for outlook. The static mode allows to keep the object when this sub is launched more than one time
Static olObject As Object   'Early binding: Outlook.Application

'Declaration of variable objects to open the outlook window (prevent the email to be stuck in the Outbox folder)
Dim myExplorers As Object   'Early binding: Outlook.Explorers
Dim myOlExpl As Object      'Early binding: Outlook.Explorer
Dim myFolder As Object      'Early binding: Outlook.Folder

'Error handling
On Error GoTo ErrHandler


Select Case True
    'If the olObject is nothing then try to create it
    Case olObject Is Nothing, Len(olObject.Name) = 0
        'This line will work if outlook is already opened, otherwise it will create an error and the code will go to ErrHandler
        Set olObject = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

        'If there is not already one opened windows of outlook
        If olObject.Explorers.Count = 0 Then
InitOutlook:
            'Open outlook window to prevent the email to be stucked in the Outbox folder (not sent)
            Set myExplorers = olObject.Explorers
            Set myFolder = olObject.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox: 6
            Set myOlExpl = myExplorers.Add(myFolder, 0) 'olFolderDisplayNoNavigation: 2, olFolderDisplayNormal:0
                            'Early binding code:
                            'Set myExplorers = Application.Explorers
                            'Set myFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
                            'Set myOlExpl = myExplorers.Add(myFolder, olFolderDisplayNoNavigation)
            myOlExpl.Display
        End If
End Select

'Delete the olObject variable is the ReleaseIt boolean is true
If ReleaseIt = True Then
    Set olObject = Nothing
End If

'Possibility to set the OutlookApp function as the outlook object, if OutlookApp is declared like this: "Function OutlookApp(Optional ReleaseIt As Boolean = True) as Object"
'Set OutlookApp = olObject

ExitProc:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147352567
            'User cancelled setup, silently exit
            Set olObject = Nothing
        Case 429, 462 '429: outlook was not opened, the Set olObject = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") code line above did not work
            Set olObject = CreateOutlook()  'Launch the CreateOutlook function: CreateOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            If olObject Is Nothing Then     'If the outlook object is still empty it means that there is a more serious issue (outlook not installed on the computer for example)
                Err.Raise 429, "OutlookApp", "Outlook Application does not appear to be installed."
            Else                            'If olObject is no more nothing, go back to the code above and open the outlook window
                Resume InitOutlook
            End If
        Case Else   'For any other error numbers
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Unexpected error"
    End Select
    Resume ExitProc
    Resume 'For debugging
End Sub
```

Second sub that manage to open outlook

```
Private Function CreateOutlook() As Object
'***This sub is a part to the global way to open outlook before sending an email (prevent the outbox bug, email stucked into the outbox)
'***Source: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm, late binding mode

'Error handling
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set CreateOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

ExitProc:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
Set CreateOutlook = Nothing

    Resume ExitProc
    Resume 'For debugging
End Function
```

FYI here is the code to activate the Excel window

```
Sub ActivateExcel()
'***This sub aims to activate Excel windows (so that it's in front of the windows)

'Set variable title equal to exact application window title
Dim ExcelTitleCaption As String
ExcelTitleCaption = Application.Caption

'Activate Microsoft Excel
AppActivate ExcelTitleCaption
End Sub
```

Thanks!! Topic solved